# Call a function in repl without brackets

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop

Would like to know if there is a way to call a function in python in repl just with the function name.

```
$ python -i interace.py
>>> load 834.png
>>> sharpen
>>> save
```

rather than

```
$ python -i interface.py
>>> load('834.png')
>>> sharpen()
>>> save()
```

reason being, I have a file `instructions.txt` that has the format as above. I wish to just do `$ python -i interface.py < instructions.txt`.
And for the times when I don't have an instruction file, I can just enter my instructions manually.

Comment: `python -i` is designed to run an interactive Python session. You're not looking for an interactive Python session. You should write your own input handling.

Comment: Agree with @user2357112supportsMonica.  Your instruction format looks trivial to parse, and you can read input with `for line in sys.stdin:`

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this with the regular Python interpreter. [Function calls *must* include parentheses.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls)

Now, your instructions look a lot like shell syntax, so maybe what you could do is write your own simple parser. Try looking at [shlex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) to start.

---

By the way, if it helps, IPython includes an [`%autocall`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-autocall) setting that almost does what you want.

```
In [4]: print 'hello'                                                                                 
  File "<ipython-input-4-5a1ef41e7057>", line 1
    print 'hello'
                ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('hello')?


In [5]: %autocall                                                                                      
Automatic calling is: Smart

In [6]: print 'hello'                                                                                 
------> print('hello')
hello

In [7]: print 834.png                                                                                 
------> print(834.png)
  File "<ipython-input-7-3d64d8523fdd>", line 1
    print(834.png)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```